# Extract tag contents based on value of another tag qualifier using xmllint

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmllint

I'm trying to use xmllint to extract data from a tag if a condition exists on a previous tag. I know there are probably better tools but I'm limited to xmllint and/or system standard commands like sed, awk, etc.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MainGroup>
<MainGroupEntry name="aaa" function="xxx">
    <EntryType type="AAA"/>
    <EntryDescription>Capture This A</EntryDescription>
    <EntryRandomList>Just,a,random,list,of,things,to,discard</EntryRandomList>
</MainGroupEntry>
<MainGroupEntry name="aaa" function="xxx">
    <EntryType type="AAA"/>
    <EntryDescription>Capture This A</EntryDescription>
    <EntryRandomList>Just,a,random,list,of,things,to,discard</EntryRandomList>
</MainGroupEntry>
<MainGroupEntry name="bbb" function="yyy">
    <EntryType type="BBB"/>
    <EntryDescription>Capture This B</EntryDescription>
    <EntryRandomList>Just,a,random,list,of,things,to,discard</EntryRandomList>
</MainGroupEntry>
<MainGroupEntry name="bbb" function="yyy">
    <EntryType type="BBB"/>
    <EntryDescription>Capture This B</EntryDescription>
    <EntryRandomList>Just,a,random,list,of,things,to,discard</EntryRandomList>
</MainGroupEntry>
</MainGroup>
```

What I'm "trying to do is; for every `Entry type="AAA"`, print the accompanying `EntryDescription`. I've tried different variations of: `xmllint --xpath '//MainGroupEntry/EntryType[@type="AAA"]/EntryDescription/text()' my_file.xml` but I always get an empty XPath set. If I drop trying to get the Description text, I can see the entries that match my 'type' condition:

`xmllint --xpath '//MainGroupEntry/EntryType[@type="AAA"]' my_file.xml 
<EntryType type="AAA"/><EntryType type="AAA"/>`

I just can't seem to figure out how to only grab the text from the Description field.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `following-sibling` axis and the `text()` function to extract only the text from the description:

```
xmllint --xpath '/MainGroup/MainGroupEntry/EntryType[@type="AAA"]/following-sibling::EntryDescription/text()' file.xml
```

To separate the texts, you can use the `--shell` option with `cat`:

```
echo 'cat /MainGroup/MainGroupEntry/EntryType[@type="AAA"]/following-sibling::EntryDescription/text()' \
| xmllint --shell file.xml
```

You might need to `| grep -v ' -----\|/ >'` the output to remove the separators and prompt.

Comment: that did it! Thanks! follow up question (and this is me being lazy) any easy way to print them off one response per line?